# Retrieving Data From MySQL Against Specific Record Already Not Exist

Tags: java, mysql, jcombobox

Actually i'm confused in fetching data from `MySql DB`. I've two tables `Room` and `Dentist` . in `Dentist Form` i'm using `Combobox` to show `RoomID` as show in picture below with red cricle. In that `Combobox` i want to show only those `RoomID` , which don't have `DentistID`. What will be `MySql Query` for that.

[image: screenshot of my form]

My `DataBase` Pics of both tables `Room & Dentist` are given Below. In `Room Table` `InchargeID` and in `Dentist Table` , `DentistID` both are same with different name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: why `java` and `php` ?

Comment: These are tables, not DataBases. For next time see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - and can a dentist really never have more than one room? Either way, it seems highly unlikely that two dentists would refer to the same room by different names.

Comment: It seems you did the annotation in MS Paint! :D

Comment: @Nobody LOL! Yeah :D :D

Comment: @Strawberry , It was written by mistake... yes from my point of view dentist can have more than one room... as he/she is dentist he may work in different rooms but he/she could not be incharge of more than one rooms. From the below answer i got my solution. Anyway thanks for your precious time sir :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I think you need room id which doesn't allocated to any dentist. So You can get it from following query:

```
SELECT Room.RoomID FROM Room WHERE Room.RoomID NOT IN (SELECT Dentist.RoomID FROM Dentist);
```

Comment: Thanks very much... by modifying your answer i got solution of my question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use join with the tables, and also use `is null` with the column name where you want to apply 'null' condition . you can find below query for find all data from `Room` and `Dentist` where DentistID is null.

```
select Room.*, Dentist.* from Dentist right join Room on Dentist.RoomID = Room.RoomID where Dentist.DentistID is null;
```

Comment: Note that this particular is formulation is fantastically rare; the LEFT JOIN equivalent being by far the more popular of the two alleles.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the table where you store the rooms is named `rooms`, and that the `InchargeID` field allows null values, this should be enough:

`select RoomID from rooms where InchargeID is null;`

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99531/2) where you can test it.